# How jmeter execute threads?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have set as per following :

**

**- Users : 20 Ramp-up Period : 30 Loop count :1**

**

What actually it means Thread group 1-2 , 1-3 ... How jmeter consider my 20 user to execute request?

When my jmeter script runs , I can see following in Log viewer :

2014/11/27 03:45:59 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-2 
2014/11/27 03:46:00 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-3 
2014/11/27 03:46:02 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-4 
2014/11/27 03:46:03 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-5 
2014/11/27 03:46:05 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-6 
2014/11/27 03:46:06 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-7 
2014/11/27 03:46:08 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-8 
2014/11/27 03:46:09 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-9 
2014/11/27 03:46:11 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-10 
2014/11/27 03:46:12 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-11 
2014/11/27 03:46:14 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-12 
2014/11/27 03:46:15 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-13 
2014/11/27 03:46:17 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1 
2014/11/27 03:46:17 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-14 
2014/11/27 03:46:18 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-15 
2014/11/27 03:46:20 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-16 
2014/11/27 03:46:21 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-17 
2014/11/27 03:46:22 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-2 
2014/11/27 03:46:23 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-18 
2014/11/27 03:46:24 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-19 
2014/11/27 03:46:26 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-20 
2014/11/27 03:46:27 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-3 
2014/11/27 03:46:37 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-4 
2014/11/27 03:46:41 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-5 
2014/11/27 03:46:43 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-6 
2014/11/27 03:47:09 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-7 
2014/11/27 03:47:25 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-8 
2014/11/27 03:47:26 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-9 
2014/11/27 03:47:32 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-10 
2014/11/27 03:47:40 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-11 
2014/11/27 03:47:51 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-12 
2014/11/27 03:47:58 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-13 
2014/11/27 03:48:06 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-15 
2014/11/27 03:48:07 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-14 
2014/11/27 03:48:11 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-16 
2014/11/27 03:48:15 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-17 
2014/11/27 03:48:16 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-18 
2014/11/27 03:48:17 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-19 
2014/11/27 03:48:18 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-20

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jmeter is a Java application which uses multithreading.

Since your Thread Group settings are: Users : 20 Ramp-up Period : 30 Loop count :1

So it will create 20 threads representing 20 Users, and each user will execute your thread group 1 time.

Since you have only 1 thread group in your test plan, That is why your Log shows

Thread started: Thread Group 1-1, Thread Group 1-2, Thread Group 1-3 ..........

The second number represents the user.

hope this will help.